# SSIS Package when deployed as a scheduled package is not stopping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have 3 packages out of which 2 are designed by me and 1 was designed by another developer.All the 3 packages have independent functionality.

I have deployed all the 3 packages as a scheduled jobs(3 independent scheduled jobs). The packages which i created are working fine as jobs.

But the package which the other developer has developed is in continuous loop and not getting completed.This package only copies data from one db to different db.

None of us have admin rights on this server. all the deployed packages executes through proxy account which has admin rights.

Please let me know how to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the 3 jobs running simultaneously? Are they accessing the same tables of a database?

Comment: No they are running at different intervals of time and all of them work on different databases.

Comment: Create a table which logs the progress of the package.  I assume you cant do sp_who2 or anything then?

Comment: try to run the package (developed by other person) in your local  and see if you are able to run

Comment: Why is it hanging? What does the package do? Conceptually and physically. Post a screenshot of the Control Flow, the data flow(s) and anything else that might give us a clue as to why this package is behaving differently. Also, I find that enabling logging and the OnPreExecute and OnPostExecute events will help you at least identify which tasks have started and completed.

Comment: @CatchingMonkey  thanks i will try to log the details. Yes i cannot use sp_who2

Comment: @RahulSharma  thanks i have already tried it and i am able to execute the package locally and it is working as expected. It is behaving different only when i deploy the package as a scheduled job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run the deployed jobs through proxy account.
The proxy account user did not have rights to one of the database where it will pull the data from.
After granting the access to that database for the proxy user the deployed package worked successfully.

Thank you all for your valuable time and suggestions.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. The package should have failed with an error.

Answer (score 0):

Go through these links which can solve your problem :

Please refer to Jason's reply in the following link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/910fd7b6-56b2-4804-b4f7-2d3711d88680

And here is an article talk about troubleshooting SSIS package hanged for running:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/2cb0bec7-0fe2-4b8d-b59e-9534388c72e7

also we can    try running your package from stored proc. i think it will work.

```
Create procedure [dbo].[s_ExecutePackage]
@FilePath   varchar(1000) ,

@Filename   varchar(128)

as

Declare @cmd varchar(1000)

   select @cmd =  'dtexec /F "' + @FilePath + @Filename + '"'

   exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd

go



To call the procedure

Exec [dbo].[s_ExecutePackage]   
@FilePath = 'F:\My Documents\' ,   
@FileName = 'mypackage.dtsx'
```